# How to link an instantiated File object with an input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, input, file-upload, upload

For testing purpose:

According to the W3C File API specification, it's possible to create a file object:

```
var dynamic_file = new File(["file_content_foo"], "filename.txt");
```

But how to link it to the **input file**?

```
<input type="file" id="file_to_upload"/>
<input type="submit" value="post">
```

**The goal**: Sending the post will send the dynamic_file

Comment: Something like: document.getElementById('#file').value = dynamic_file;

Comment: Typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You want to make a POST request with a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). Instead you ask us how to attach it to an `<input>` element. Just ask question X instead of question Y.